# Microsoft Teams: Error when saving/retrieving config settings

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-teams, web-parts, devextreme

I'm working on saving the configs of a custom Teams tab that I have finished developing. To do the development, I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2017,
- HTML JavaScript,
- Microsoft Teams SDK,
- App Studio (for the manifest) and
- DevExtreme controls

However, saving and retrieving the settings is making me chew bricks! The way I'm doing it is by using string manipulation to either add or extract the various settings from the URL of the tab page. However, I'm unable to either retrieve or save the setting.

Here are the problems:
- When retrieving the setting (using the retrieveSettings() method), each of the values returned are undefined.
- When saving the setting (using the btnSave_Click() method), I get this error:
[image]

Here is an excerpt of my JavaScript code:

```
var ErrorNotifyTimeoutDuration = 10000;
var NotificationDisplayDuration = 10000;

// For debugging purposes only:
var txtCurrentEntityID;
var txtCurrentName;
var txtCurrentContentUrl;
var txtCurrentWebsiteUrl;

// Represents the actual fields
var txtRecordsListTitle;
var txtBaseWebApiUrl;
var txtRecordsListTemplateID;
var txtInputValue;

$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeFrontEnd();
});

function initializeFrontEnd() {

    // Currently stored settings fields - for debugging purposes
    txtCurrentEntityID = $("#txtCurrentEntityID").dxTextBox({
        placeholder: "Current Entity ID"
    }).data("dxTextBox");

    // Repeat for the other controls as well

    $("#btnSave").dxButton({
        stylingMode: "outlined",
        text: "Save",
        type: "default",
        width: 120,
        onClick: btnSave_Click
    });

    retrieveSettings();
}


function btnSave_Click() {
    try {
        //var message = "These are the new config settings:\n";

        //var recordsListTitle = txtRecordsListTitle.option("value");
        //var baseWebApiUrl = txtBaseWebApiUrl.option("value");
        //var recordsListTemplateID = txtRecordsListTemplateID.option("value");
        //var inputValue = txtInputValue.option("value");

        //// TODO: Validations on fields, eg. length, format, etc.

        //message = message + "RecordsList Title = " + recordsListTitle + "\n";
        //message = message + "Base Web API URL = " + baseWebApiUrl + "\n";
        //message = message + "RecordsList Template ID = " + recordsListTemplateID + "\n";
        //message = message + "Input Value = " + inputValue + "\n";
        //DevExpress.ui.notify(message, "info", NotificationDisplayDuration);

        var url = AppendQueryStringToPageUrl();
        //DevExpress.ui.notify(url, "info", NotificationDisplayDuration);

        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
            microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                contentUrl: url,
                suggestedDisplayName: "User-Defined Name"
            });
            saveEvent.notifySuccess();
        });

        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

    }

    catch (error) {
        var errorMessage = "An unexpected error was encountered while updating the settings. Details:\n"
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Message: " + error.message + "\n";
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "StackTrace: " + error.stack;

        DevExpress.ui.notify(errorMessage, "error", ErrorNotifyTimeoutDuration);
    }
}

function retrieveSettings() {

    try {
        var currentEntityId;
        var currentName;
        var currentContentUrl;
        var currentWebsiteUrl;

        var currentSettings;

        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
        microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function (settings) {
            currentEntityId = settings.entityId;
            currentName = settings.name;
            currentContentUrl = settings.contentUrl;
            currentWebsiteUrl = settings.websiteUrl;

            currentSettings = settings;
        });
        //var message = "These are the retrieved config settings:\n";
        //message = message + "entityId = " + currentEntityId + "\n";
        //message = message + "name = " + currentName + "\n";
        //message = message + "contentUrl = " + currentContentUrl + "\n";
        //message = message + "websiteUrl = " + currentWebsiteUrl + "\n";
        //DevExpress.ui.notify(message, "info", NotificationDisplayDuration);

        txtRecordsListTitle.option("value", currentEntityId);
        txtBaseWebApiUrl.option("value", currentName);
        txtRecordsListTemplateID.option("value", currentContentUrl);
        txtInputValue.option("value", currentWebsiteUrl);
    }

    catch (error) {
        var errorMessage = "An unexpected error was encountered while retrieving the settings. Details:\n"
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Message: " + error.message + "\n";
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "StackTrace: " + error.stack;

        DevExpress.ui.notify(errorMessage, "error", ErrorNotifyTimeoutDuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing the teams library at wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where should it be initialized? Should it be initialized in the HTML in the body inside a <script> block?

Comment: it should be in script block before you call any teams client method.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try that! :)

Comment: I tried putting the microsoftTeams.initialize(); statement in a completely separate script block, but I still get the same error.